Cellulase-producing plants, in any phase of their growth, in similar amounts to amylase in other plants
Daikons and barley sprouts are able to make amylase. What similar cases exist where plants may create cellulase in similar amounts?

Seedlings of many species produce amylases to convert starches in the endosperm to usable sugars. I'm not aware of any plants that produce cellulase in amounts sufficient to break down large amounts of cellulose. But see Do plants have cellulases? and the article linked in the comments for discussion of the role of cellulases in cellulose microfibril formation in plants.
